# Binding canvas boxes to grids, and checking collision

Tags: canvas, collision-detection, pixel

Ive got a canvas (300x300) with 4 already placed 15 x 15 squares.

I want to do two things....
First...

Check for collision with Pink Boxes when I create a new Red Box by clicking.

This is the most important.  I simply want to know when a red square overlaps a pink one, and which pink one.

The less important second thing I'd like...

Limit all placed 'pixels' to a grid.  So they can't overlap, but instead adhere to a 15x15 grid only.
Or whatever size I want.

[CHECK FIDDLE FOR EXMAPLE/CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/AYk42/2/)

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

    var red = 255;
    var green = 0;
    var blue = 0;

    var pixRes = 15;

    function handleMouseDown(e) {
        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
        Player.enterMove(mouseX,mouseY, red, green, blue);
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
        handleMouseDown(e);
    });



var Player =
{

   moves : [],
   positions: [[118,103],[183,195],[137,261],[37,136]],
   positionMap: {},

   initPositions: function(){
     $.each(this.positions, function(i,val){
        setPixel(val[0],val[1], 255,0,255);
    });
},

 enterMove: function(x, y, red, green, blue)
 { 
this.moves.push([x,y]);
setPixel(x, y, red, green, blue);
this.checkHit(x,y);


},

 checkHit: function(x,y){
    //Do checking here



}

};
  var p = Player;
  p.initPositions();
```

Comment: check in the console of your fiddle, you forgot to insert the generateRenderMap code.

Comment: Yeah, I know....I meant to remove all that....uts not doing anything right now anyway..

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately, i don't have time right now to go further, but check this fiddle, it might help you : http://jsfiddle.net/AYk42/3/

Comment: Thats perfect GameAlchemist!  Thanks!!....if you wanna write it as an answer, Ill accept it :)

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AYk42/9/ try to let the button pushed, and try when more than 2 cell neighbors are filled.

Comment: Wow, thats actually almost the end result Im picturing.  Did you just make that??